# TensorFlow in production for real time predictions in high traffic app - how to use?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

What is the right way to use TensorFlow for real time predictions in a high traffic application.

Ideally I would have a server/cluster running tensorflow listening on a port(s) where I can connect from app servers and get predictions similar to the way databases are used.
Training should be done by cron jobs feeding the training data through the network to the same server/cluster.

How does one actually use tensorflow in production? Should I build a setup where the python is running as a server and use the python scripts to get predictions? I'm still new to this but I feel that such script will need to open sessions etc.. which is not scalable. (I'm talking about 100s of predictions/sec).

Any pointer to relevant information will be highly appreciated. I could not find any.

Comment: At present the public version of TensorFlow does not scale up as you noted; in the future it should based on what I have read here at SO. Timeframe unknown.

Comment: If I understand correctly the version doesnt scale in terms of having multiple servers running in parallel. Does the open source version also lack the interface to the application layer ?? I can start with moderate throughput but I still need the right way to interface it

Comment: I don't know. Maybe [mrry](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3574081/mrry) will see this and respond. You also might want to change the question as it has 3 close votes now. I did not give you one, but I do think it is a question that should not be removed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This morning, our colleagues released [TensorFlow Serving](http://tensorflow.github.io/serving/) on GitHub, which addresses some of the use cases that you mentioned. It is a distributed wrapper for TensorFlow that is designed to support high-performance serving of multiple models. It supports both bulk processing and interactive requests from app servers.

For more information, see the [basic](http://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic) and [advanced](http://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_advanced) tutorials.

Comment: Hey @mrry, Can this also be hosted locally like say on a laptop app, or even on a single board computer (raspberry pi, intel joule, etc)?