# TensorFlow in production: How to retrain your models

Tags: tensorflow, supervised-learning, tensorflow-serving

I have a question related to this one:

[TensorFlow in production for real time predictions in high traffic app - how to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414824/tensorflow-in-production-for-real-time-predictions-in-high-traffic-app-how-to)

I want to setup TensorFlow Serving to do inference as a service for our other application. I see how TensorFlow Serving helps me to do that. Additionally, it mentions a [continuous training pipeline](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/), which probably is related to the possibility that TensorFlow Serving can serve with multiple versions of a trained model. But what I am not sure is how to retrain your model as you get new data. The other post mentions the idea to run retraining with cron jobs. However, I am not sure if automatic retraining is a good idea. What architecture would you propose for a continuous retraining pipeline with a system continuously facing new, labelled data?

Edit: It is a supervised learning case. The question is would you automatically retrain your model after n new datapoints came in or would you retrain during the downtime of the customer automatically or just retrain manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use some kind of semi-supervised training. There's fairly extensive research in that area.

A crude, but expedient way, which works well, is to use the current best models that you have to label the new, incoming data. Models are typically able to produce a score (hopefully a logprob). You can use that score to only train on the data that fits well.

That is an approach that we have used in speech recognition and is an excellent baseline.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that sounds quite well for other tasks that we have. I actually was more interested in how you swap your old model with the new model in a supervised, continuous retraining case. Meaning if you have your model x, and you see n new, labelled datapoints, when do you retrain to improve your model to x+1? Do you even trigger on number of datapoints or would you rerun it during the downtime of the customer if possible? Or would you only rerun manually and not rollout automatically?

Comment: There are two approaches, both are used, for different reasons. They require some level of scale. In the first one, we have a team of data scientists, constantly improving the algorithms, and utilizing more data. Then, every week, they meet up for a launch committee. Each improvement that goes to the algorithm has to be approved. In the other approach, mechanically, every, say Wednesday, a branch is cut with the models. Then it's pushed with whatever is at head. In both cases, we phase in the new model/code in the service service and it is being monitored for latency, memory, accuracy, etc.