# CNTK deployment for real time predictions

Tags: cntk

TensorFlow has a separate project for its production usage, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35414824/tensorflow-in-production-for-real-time-predictions-in-high-traffic-app-how-to), called TensorFlow Serving.

How should I use CNTK in a production environment, and how should I handle it's deployment? Hopefully one could deploy trained models in to a server/cluster that serves the model with RPC or HTTP REST API.

If no such tool exists, what should be the first steps to develop it and a good architecture to roll out on my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do support serving CNTK models in a production environment. You can find information about model evaluation/inference: https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Evaluation-Overview. For deployment, you need deploy the dlls specified [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Library-Evaluation-on-Windows#shipping-cntk-library-with-your-windows-application). A tutorial for deploying CNTK in Azure is available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Evaluate-a-model-in-an-Azure-WebApi).

Comment: nice, an Azure tutorial is more than I was hoping!

Answer (score 0):

No such tool exists from the CNTK team, but the new APIs in C++ or python should make the task pretty easy once you have a trained model.